# What are the effects of chocolate on babies?

Tags: infant

I fed my baby the chocolate on the chips ahoy cookie. I didn't feed him the whole cookie, just one piece of the chocolate and cookie. This is the first time. We had a bad night because he kept crying. I am wondering about other effects of choocolate and i felt bad at myself feeding him that. As a first time mom, i don't know what to do so the chocolate is removed in his system? He is turning 1 yr old this weekend

Comment: I don't have research for this, so I will only comment. A baby almost one year old should be able to digest a little bit of cookie. Many babies get their first very messy piece of cake on their first birthday. His upset in the night was probably just a coincidence, but do watch for patterns as you introduce new foods just in case there is a sensitivity.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't jump to any conclusions from one feeding of chocolate. It may just be a coincidence. Keep monitoring your baby for the possibility that he's becoming ill from something else.

Regarding chocolate, it does have caffeine; not as much as coffee, but if this is the first time your baby was exposed to caffeine, and you gave him the cookie later in the day, it may just be that he was crying because he wasn't sleeping well.

Infants process most foods in the same way as adults. There are no reliable ways to help a baby (or adult) to decrease processing time. The caffeine and other things in chocolate (flavinoids, etc.) are no longer in his system, just as they are no longer in yours from your half of the cookie.

It's ok to give a small amount of chocolate to babies after a year of age (it depends on your attitude towards sweets); wait a couple of weeks and try it during the first part of the day. If he fusses later after eating, best to avoid it until you can speak to your doctor.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I am relieved. As a first time mommy my anxieties are sometimes way beyond. My son is better now :)